# Scientific notation to decimal

Tags: java, decimal, scientific-notation, decimalformat

I have a double and i am trying to convert it to a decimal. When i use decimalformat to achieve this i get the following:

```
public void roundNumber(){
    double d = 2.081641999208976E-4;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,roundFiveDecimals(d));
}

public double roundFiveDecimals(double d) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
    return Double.valueOf(df.format(d));
}
```

I want the output to be .00021; however, i get 2.1E-4. Can anyone help explain how to get .00021 and not 2.1E-4?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're *parsing* the result from `DecimalFormat` - you should be *returning* it as a `String`:

```
public String roundFiveDecimals(double d) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
    return df.format(d);
}
```

The `double` value itself has no concept of formatting - it's just a number. It's the job of `DecimalFormat` to format the value into text however you want... if you then convert that text *back* into a number, you've lost that work.