# Long float-number output shows letters

Tags: java, floating-point

I have the following code:

```
String curDir = ".";
File fileObject = new File(curDir);
File[] fileList = fileObject.listFiles();

float fileLengthMegabytes = (float)fileList[i].length() / 1000000;
```

The method fileList[i].length() returns 311 bytes as the type Long.

The previous code results in the following output:

3.88E-4

**How do I get my expected output of 0,000311 inside the fileLengthMegabytes variable?**

Comment: that's a perfectly normal floating point display type. `E` represents `times 10 to the power of`, e.g. "3.88 times 10 to the power of -4".

Comment: It looks like you're just printing scientific notation.  The value hasn't changed.  Check out [java number format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

Comment: How many duplicate answers do we need?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is Scientific Notation.

AND you are getting 388 instead of 311 because you are dividing by 1000000 instead of 1048576 (1024 * 1024)

EDIT: 311 is not achieved even with 1048576, that way you get 370... so the error is probably in your calc ;)

As [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878623/scientific-notation-to-decimal) , you just have to convert your Scientific Notation to a Decimal Notation through a Formatter.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
return df.format(fileLengthMegabytes);
```

**Running Example**: http://ideone.com/2lkKv7

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");

        float fileLengthMegabytes1 = (float) 388 / 1000000;
        float fileLengthMegabytes2 = (float) 388 / 1048576;
        System.out.println("MB1 in Scientific Notation: " + 
                            fileLengthMegabytes1);        
        System.out.println("MB1 in Decimal Notation: " + 
                            df.format(fileLengthMegabytes1));
        System.out.println("MB2 in Scientific Notation: " + 
                            fileLengthMegabytes2);        
        System.out.println("MB2 in Decimal Notation: " + 
                            df.format(fileLengthMegabytes2));
        }
}
```

Output:

> MB1 in Scientific Notation: 3.88E-4
>
> MB1 in Decimal Notation: 0.000388
>
> MB2 in Scientific Notation: 3.7002563E-4
>
> MB2 in Decimal Notation: 0.0003700256

Answer (score 6):

This is the way Java(and many other languages) display floating point numbers. `E` just means `10^`, so `3.88E-4` is another way of writing `3.88 x 10^-4`, which is the same as `0.000388`.

This format is called [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). [E-notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) is a computer representation of scientific notation.

The rest of your inaccuracy (388 vs 311) is because 1000000 is not the exact number you want to be dividing by. See the other answers for more details.

Comment: is there a way to replace `E` with `10^` while printing it?

Answer (score 1):

3.88E-4 as mentioned before is a representation in the [scientific E-notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

If you want to print it or convert to String you can write something like that:

```
System.out.printf("%f%n", fileLengthMegabytes);
// or
String fileLengthMegabytesMessage = String.format(
        "File size is %fMb", fileLengthMegabytes);
System.out.println(fileLengthMegabytesMessage);
```

and you've got:

```
0,000311
// or 
File size is 0,000311Mb
```

respectfully

Answer (score 0):

If you want normal numbers (without scientific notation), use `BigInteger`

```
BigInteger inbytes = new BigInteger("" + fileList[i].length());
BigInteger inMB = inBytes.divide(new BigInteger("" + (1024*1024)));
```

Note: Normal `double` value would also suffice.

Answer (score 0):

To get the notation you want, use a formatter:

```
final Formatter f = new Formatter();
final String out = f.format("%8.6f", fileLengthMegabytes);
```

should give you your result.

See also:
[Java Doc: String.Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), 
[Java Doc: Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)