# Struts 2 - Double with scientific notation issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, struts2, double, scientific-notation

I'm having a problem dealing with Struts 2 and Javascript. This is the javascript code:

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitud = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitud = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    document.getElementById("goPlans_evo_latitud").value = latitud;
                    document.getElementById("goPlans_evo_longitud").value = longitud;
                    document.getElementById("goPlans").submit();
                } 
            });
```

When I'm trying to print these two values (latitude & longitude) on the script side it returns this (p.ex.):

**41.3970035 2.189719200000013**

And if I print them on the action method (after struts 2 set those values on Double objects) it returns this:

**4.13970035E8 2.189719200000013E15**

I noticed that this a scientific notation. I could try to format them but these values are wrong formatted.

This the action method (very simple):

```
public String goPlans() {
    System.out.println(evo.getLatitud() + " " + evo.getLongitud());
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Can someone help me to know how set correctly these values using Struts 2?

Thank you.

**EDIT: I found the problem! I need to declare the longitude and latitude bean variables as double (primitive) not as Double (Class).**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display whole number in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129753/how-do-i-display-whole-number-in-javascript) or [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: The problem isn't in the Javascript side I think. It's on the action method side.

Comment: What if you `console.log(latitud)` and/or `console.log(longitud)`?

Comment: Show the code where did you print them, then you'll probably get answered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13363576/1654265

Comment: But if you see, on the System.out, it prints a wrong number (4.13970035E8 is not 41.3970035)

Comment: If you've found answer to your question then post it in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! I need to declare the longitude and latitude bean variables as double (primitive) not as Double (Class).