# I can format a number value of a textfiled but can not update it

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl

I am trying to update few number values on a form. Once the values are shown without formation, I can easily change them to any number and correct number will be sent to the back-end; however, if I enter a big number such as 6000000, it will be changed to 6.0E7 on browser,  but correct number will be sent to the back-end. I added fmt library to format the number but when I submit the form it sends 0 to the back-end.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<s:textfield id="price" name="price" value="%{price}" theme="simple"/>  //6.0E7


<input name="price" id="price" value='<fmt:formatNumber value='${price}'/>'/> //0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use JSTL's fmt, Struts2 has inbuilt **[Formatting Utilities](http://struts.apache.org/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html)**:

- [MUST READ: Using Struts2 Tags to Formatting Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20520668/1654265)

Then instead of

```xml
<s:textfield name="price" value="%{price}" />  
<!-- output: 6.0E7 -->
```

use for example

```xml
<s:textfield name="price" value="%{getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}', {price})}" />
<!-- output: 6000000.00 -->
```

Also read about [Type Conversion](http://struts.apache.org/docs/type-conversion.html), and keep in mind that 6.0E7 is [Scientific Notation](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation&ei=LDE9U7ujLPOByQPup4GAAw&usg=AFQjCNEc5fyT87B3Y9LcI36YbaHySE1VKw&sig2=DtHK_uZmHhjYr39a9xo0lQ&bvm=bv.63934634,d.bGQ) (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13363576/1654265)).

Answer (score 1):

How using `pattern` property,

```
<input name="price" id="price" value=
    '<fmt:formatNumber value='${price}' pattern="##,####,###"/>'
/>
```

or `type` and `groupingUsed` like

```
<input name="price" id="price" value=
    '<fmt:formatNumber value='${price}' type="number" groupingUsed="false"/>'
/>
```