# Numbers not formatted properly in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, localization, numbers, format, ognl

I am using following syntax  to display a value in a proper number format, e.g. `1,250.00`.

```xml
<s:property value="%{getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',#plan.amount)}" />
```

However, it is not working. The `plan` is an object with a property amount.

Comment: What value is printed to the out?

Comment: The databeing displayed is 1250.00 without the the comma.

Comment: @AleksandrM It's not true.

Comment: @AleksandrM It's not clear what is the type of list. I suspect that it doesn't work with *all* lists. I will wait for good solution of my question or delete it because no interest from the community.

Comment: @AleksandrM I have explained it enough, if you understand this question, then you should understand my question, the difference only to understand my answer below you have to put some effort to understand the problem. And it congrats you afterwords.

Comment: @VikramSingh *The pound sign (#) denotes a digit, the comma is a placeholder for the grouping separator, and the period is a placeholder for the decimal separator.*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value is printed like `1250.00` then it's not formatted properly. The method `getText()` has many overloaded methods and which method is used is determined by the parameter's types and count.

To pass arguments to the `getText()` method you can use OGNL list construction `{}`. And the arguments should be listed as single values, not "list of object". Perfectly it should be list of `Double` with one element inside the list.

```jsp
<s:set var="amount" value="%{1250.0}"/>
<s:property value="%{getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',{#amount})}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to display multiple values from a list, you need an iterator;

second, if `plan` is a list in the action with a getter method

```
public List<Something> getPlan() { return plan; }
```

then you don't have to put the `#` ahead of the variable.

The right code for your case would be:

```xml
<s:iterator value="plan">
    <s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',{amount})" />
</s:iterator>
```

There's a [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22834359/1654265) on the topic.

---

**EDIT**

Since you have

> ```xml
> <s:iterator value="list" var="plan" status="status"> 
>     <div class="values"> 
>         $ <s:property value="%{getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',#plan.amount)}"/> 
>     </div>
> </s:iterator>
> ```

Then it should be:

```xml
<s:iterator value="list">
    <s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',{amount})" />
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Hi, I am using an iterator. Also, I am using getter in action class. if I remove # before the variable, it doesn't display any data.

Comment: Please show all the relevant part of your action, and JSP (iterator etc...)

Comment: <s:iterator value="list" var="plan" status="status">    <div class="values">
        $
        <s:property value="%        {getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',#plan.amount)}" /> 
       </div></s:iterator>

Comment: This one also worked. I think the key here is to use {} curly braces for the parameter. Thank you so much for providing solution :)

Comment: This is the first answer you got, and it works. Why are you accepting the other one, that is identical to mine ?

Comment: I am using the previous answer in my code. I tried to accept both, but it is not letting me do it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: So you are using mine, with an unnecessary s:set operation before ? Nice