# How to convert a string into a float?

Tags: java, android, string, valueconverter

I am trying to convert String value "0.00008241" into Float as it is

what I can try

```
 String price="0.00008241";
 Float f1=Float.parseFloat(price);
 Float f2=Float.valueOf(price);
 Double f3 =Double.parseDouble(price);
 Double f4 =Double.valueOf(price);
```

but all these return 8.241E-5

then I try it with BigDecimal

```
BigDecimal tt= BigDecimal.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(price));
```

it returns 0.00008240999886766076

so any help to convert that price value as it is?

still cant convert it still string?

```
String price_="0.00008241";
        BigDecimal tt= BigDecimal.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(price_));
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");
        float price = Float.parseFloat("0.00008241");
        String sPrice= df.format(price);
```

The BigDecimal value can we compare with double value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long float-number output shows letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363429/long-float-number-output-shows-letters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big Decimal is perfect for this conversation:

```
           String price="0.00008241";
           BigDecimal decimal=new BigDecimal(price);
           System.out.println(decimal); //0.00008241
```

Comment: it is possible to convert decimal to an other type ? like long

Comment: Yes it is possible decimal.doubleValue() but return same "8.241E-5" make your all operation in for example decimal.divide(somevalue)

Comment: so how to compare that with double value ?

Comment: double comp=1.1;
 decimal.compareTo(new BigDecimal(comp));

Answer (score 3):

```
 Double f4 =Double.valueOf(price);
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#########");
 String after_convert=df.format(f4);
 System.out.println(after_convert);
```

Comment: Note, however, that doubles aren't exact. Considering it's names "price" and OP wants to compare values, a BigDecimal is more likely to do the job. That or using longs that represent billionths of the unit.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for like this. I'm not sure it is but here is

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("0.00008241");
System.out.println(bd.toString());
BigDecimal result = bd.add(new BigDecimal("0.005"));
System.out.println(result.toString());
```